# Sufficient condition for moduli space of slope-stable bundles to be non-empty

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, low-dimensional-topology, gauge-theory, geometric-invariant-theory

I'm trying to find to a statement concerning the non-emptiness of the moduli space of slope stable vector bundles over a Kähler surface in the literature.

Let $X$ be a Kähler surface. Let $\mathscr{M}(c_1, r, c_2)$ be the moduli space of all slope stable complex vector bundles $V$ over $X$ of rank $r$ with $c_1(V) = c_1$ and $c_2(V) = c_2$. Donaldson-Uhlenbeck-Yau show that there is an isomorphism
$$\mathscr{M}(0,2,c_2) \leftrightarrow \{\text{ASD } SU(2) \text{ connections over } X\}/\text{ gauge group}.$$
Taubes also has shown that for an arbitrary $4-$manifold $M$ and $g$ is any Riemann metric on $M$ and $P$ is an $SU(2)-$principal bundle over $M$, the moduli space $\mathscr{M}(P, c_2,g)$ of ASD $SU(2)$ connections of $P$ is non-empty *if $c_2 = c_2(P)$ is sufficiently large*. Thus in the Kähler case, for *sufficiently large* $c_2$, $\mathscr{M}(0,2,c_2) \neq \emptyset$.

My questions:

1. What exactly is this *sufficiently large* value of $c_2$? Is there a precise bound?
2. Is there an analogous statement for higher rank case when $r>2$?

Comment: Have you examined Taubes' work? In theory, this sort of explicit bound should be either something you can extract from the proof, or something you can obtain by working out the proof in greater detail and precision.

Comment: I came across this statement by Taubes when reading through Smooth 4-manifolds and Complex surfaces by Friedman and Morgan. In there, their reference for this statement by Taubes is the paper Self dual Yang Mills connections on non-self dual 4-manifolds. I couldn't find such a statement in that paper.

Comment: I just glanced at Taubes' introduction, and the first theorem stated is one about existence of a single connection of a certain type, hence a non-emptiness statement, and it looks to be the only such theorem listed in the intro. Assuming this is the right theorem, you may need to specialize the statement to the Kähler case and/or translate from Pontryagin classes to Chern classes in order to get the version in Friedman-Morgan.